# Home directory permissions in linux with public_html folder and alpine mail

Tags: permissions

Strangely enough, I haven't found a satisfactory answer to this question.
I need to set up proper permissions for my university server home directory:

1. public access to the public_html/ sub-folder of my home folder
2. no access (read/write/execute) to anything else in my home folder
3. access for my thunderbird client to relevant alpine files

So far, I have set `701` for my home folder, `755` for public_html subfoler and `700` for other files and directories. Is that fine? Any potential problems with it?

How about newly created files and directories, how do I make them 700 by default?

Answer (score 1):

If the directories are set up that way and you are not the first student, you can assume that the permissions will be fine. If you don't think so, then explain why.

1. Your home directory has `701` or `u=rwx,o=x` to allow the web server access to `public_html`. As a consequence, others (but not group) can access files or directories with known names, provided the files or directories allow that access
2. Your `public_html` should be fine, `705` should also work but doesn't make a difference.
3. `700` means access only for you.

You shouldn't create new files with `700`, unless you want them executable. Just add

```
umask 077
```

to your `.profile` or in the shell to create files with `600` and directories with `700`. Use just `umask` to see the current value, with your setup it is probably already configured this way.

Comment: "you can assume that the permissions will be fine. If you don't think so, then explain why." Because I did the set-up just by guesswork.

Comment: I created a new file .profile in my home, but the "umask 077" did not do what I wanted, a file created in vim has permissions 644. What to do?

Comment: The `.profile` is evaluated when you login or with the command `source .profile`.

Comment: be aware, the 1 in 701 means anyone can read and edit the contents of a file in this directory, assuming they have read and write access permissions on the file itself too.